# Mac:Upgrade from 10.5.8 to Snow leopard 10.6?

Tags: mac

I would like to upgrade my mac from 10.5.8 to Snow leopard 10.6. I searched around the google but didn't get any clear info from Apple sites. Is it possible? Are there any steps to follow this from Apple sites? Is there any possibility to do it without wiping the existing software and files?

Thank you. I appreciate your helps.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible. Go to an Apple store and buy 10.6. It's not a free upgrade.

Comment: It's almost free: $29 IIRC

Answer (score 0):

Yes as @deceze said. All you need to do is buy 10.6 and install it. You should get a faster system that takes up less room on the hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is here, but an upgrade using the Snow Leopard disc was pretty pain free and only involved about 6 clicks and about 1/2 hour of my time.
The standard upgrade leaves all your programs and data in place - you may need to upgrade some apps, though.